# How to get rid of this warning of EF in Visual Studio 2019: A version of Entity Framework older than 6.3 is also installed

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget-package

I just added EntityFramework 6.4.4 to the project with the command:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version:6.4.4
```

And then, I enabled migrations. Since then, every time I execute an EF command, I get the warning:

> A version of Entity Framework older than 6.3 is also installed. The
> newer tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Update-Database' for the
> older version.

It's annoying. How can I get rid of it? I have tried to do:

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
```

But it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It sounds like there was an older version of Entity Framework that had interacted with that database. EF will create a _MigrationsHistory table which includes a product version column. The new version of EF is reporting that you should run the Update-Database command from Migrations to ensure that the table is brought up to date.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem after I had tried to downgrade my EF version to 6.2 from 6.4.4. I now had both versions installed in my packages folder under the main solution. I had to delete the 6.2 version folder and this problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @allan answer, this is not evident from the Nuget Packages as it only shows the latest one. You will have to manually explore to the folder and delete the older ones.